# Probability of getting a 6 on at least one die from a pair of dependent dice

Tags: probability, dice

I am stuck on this particular question: Suppose you have two dice. These dice however are not independent: the probability that both dice will roll a 6 is 0.29. What is the probability that at least one of them rolls a 6 given that these dice are not independent? You can treat each die as fair when considering a single die's roll.

I was doing the following:
Let $A$ be the event that the first die rolls a $6$ and let $B$ be the event that the second die rolls a $6$. Now, since $P(A \cap B) = 0.29$, I use the following to find when we get a 6 on the first die only:

$$
P (A) = P(A \cap B) \ + P(A \cap B^c)
$$

However, since we treat the roll of one die as being fair, $P(A) = 1/6$ which implies $P(A \cap B^c)$ is negative so I am definitely doing something wrong  but I am not too sure what to do

Comment: Maybe the $0.29$ is $P(A \mid B) = P(B \mid A)$?  That is to say, maybe what is meant is that once you roll a $6$ on one die, the probability that the other die rolls a $6$ is $29/100$?  It's hard to guess, since there's no physical model hinted at.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion: $$\mathsf P(A\cup B)~{=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\\=\tfrac {13}{300}}$$

Notice the probability for the union is *less* than the probability for the intersection.   It should not be.

So, no you are not doing anything wrong.  You just cannot treat the die as having a fair marginal distribution yet a joint probability of $0.29$ .

Comment: This doesn't really address OP's concern with negative probabilities.  Notice that $29/100 > 1/6$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a way to solve it if i dont treat a single die as fair?